# javafx 2, CSS and focus disappearing

Tags: css, javafx-2

I've created a very simple CSS that styles two buttons. 
To the first has just been added a padding. 
To the second has been set the -fx-background-color, but the value is taken from caspian.css, that is the value it should have before it had been set.

```
.first-style { -fx-padding: 20 5 1 5; }

.second-style { -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; }
```

At this point i experience a strange behavior: the focus decoration stops working, and the second button doesn't get its blue border when focused.

[image]

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `:focused` psuedo-class to the second style to allow the focus ring to work otherwise you just overwrite it when you respecify the background color of the button in the second-style style class.

Sample CSS:

```
.root { -fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10; }
.first-style { -fx-padding: 20 5 1 5; }
.second-style { -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; }
.second-style:focused { -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color; }
```

Sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonFocusCss extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox layout = new VBox(15);
    Button b1 = new Button("B1");
    b1.getStyleClass().add("first-style");
    Button b2 = new Button("B2");
    b2.getStyleClass().add("second-style");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
    layout.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("button.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

    stage.show();
  }
}
```

**Update**

Honestly I can't explain exactly why the JavaFX CSS override mechanism works this way, I got the answer here by reviewing the default [JavaFX 2.2 caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) and following a hunch on how it might work.

The best current explanation of the rules of application for JavaFX CSS is in the CSS Reference Guide section [CSS and the JavaFX Scene Graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), though there are subtleties in this example for which you need to turn to a general CSS specification to understand things such as [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) and [specifity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: ok, you've almost got your "accepted answer" :-). the thing that would complete the answer would be a clarification on how overwriting works in css. perhaps because i'm a newbie in CSS, but i couldn't find an exaustive explanation.

Comment: Added some links to JavaFX and general css application rules.

Comment: ok, but in those docs i've found generic css rules, but what is the reason why a pseudo class is dropped if i override its "parent" class? In your "cascading order" link it just says that pseudo-classes are treated like classes.